# Loading XML via JQuery, including attribute

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm trying to use some code adapted from  [using Jquery to get XML and put into html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625266/using-jquery-to-get-xml-and-put-into-html-table). It's working almost perfect for what I want apart from the XML file I'm loading includes an attribute ID number for each item, which I can't get to load.

So the XML looks a bit like this..

```
 <Incidents>
   <Incident id="123">
     <ModTime>2016-01-23T08:00:00Z</ModTime>
     <comments>comments here</severity>
     <currentUpdate>update</currentUpdate>
     <status>Active</status>
   </incident>
 <Incidents>
   <Incident id="456">
     <ModTime>2016-01-23T08:00:00Z</ModTime>
     <comments>comments here</severity>
     <currentUpdate>update</currentUpdate>
     <status>Active</status>
   </incident>
```

I thought that I could adapt this: 
[How to parse xml attributes with jQuery alone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747335/how-to-parse-xml-attributes-with-jquery-alone)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "feed.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml){
    $('#table').append('<h2>XML</h2>'); 
    $('#table').append('<table id="show_table" border="1" >'); 
    $(xml).find('Incident').each(function(){

        var $feed = $(this);
        var id = $feed.find('Incident').attr('id');
        var mod = $feed.find('ModTime').text();
        var comments = $feed.find('comments').text();
        var update = $feed.find('currentUpdate').text();
        var status = $feed.find('status').text();


        var html = ' <tr><td >' + id + '</td><td >' + mod + '<br>' + comments     + '</td><td>' + update + '</td><td>'  + status +'</td><td > </tr>';
        $('#show_table').append(html);
    });
}
});
</script>
```

But with that all the ID rows shows is 'undefined' for each incident.

The closest I've managed to get was using...

```
        var id = $(xml).find("Disruption").attr("id");
```

but that just shows the same ID number for all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> $(xml).find('Incident')
> ```

You have got all the Incidents.

> ```
> var $feed = $(this);
> ```

Looping over each Incident, you store the element in `$feed`

> ```
> var id = $feed.find('Incident').attr('id');
> ```

You then search the **descendants** of the Incident for further Incidents (and get the id of the first one).

There aren't any Incidents stored inside other Incidents, so you don't find any (and get `undefined`, which is the id of the 1 of 0 Incident that you checked).

You just want:

```
var id = $feed.attr("id");
```